# Switching audio output to different motherboard jack

Tags: 16.04, sound

I'm using an asus motherboard and it seems like audio is only able to play through one output jack. For example my headphones which are plugged in the front work fine and display as 'Headphones' in audio outputs, however I don't see an additional audio output device (in settings > sound) for my external speakers which are plugged into the back on my motherboard. 
I want to be able to switch audio outputs on the fly. In windows, the asus driver software allowed me to treat audio inputs/outputs as separate sources and therefore displayed the addition audio output available. Is this possible?

When I unplug my headphones, my external speakers work with an audio output of 'Line Out'. Then I plug my headphones back in the front and music plays through them, with the audio output now back to 'Headphones' and the 'Line Out' audio output disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would install alsamixer.  It allows you to change the volume on different devices.  I used it when I had two sounds cards/devices.